# difference between methods and public_methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am just curious to know that what is exactly difference between `methods` and `public_methods` in Ruby?
From [RubyMonk](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/2-metaprogramming-ruby/chapters/46-code-inspection/lessons/106-inspector-gadget) **Analysis** section

> The methods method on Object allows us to tap into to the list of
>   public methods available on an Object and its ancestors. This is
>   equivalent to using public_methods. They return all the instance
>   methods and the class methods belonging to that object and the ones
>   accessible on that object's ancestors. If you want to ignore the
>   ancestors and restrict the listing to just the receiver, you can pass
>   in false to public_methods(false).

For curiosity, i also call `methods(false)`  that return different output from 
`public_methods(false)`

My sample code and output:

```
p String.methods.size
p String.public_methods.size
p String.methods(false).size
p String.public_methods(false).size
p String.public_methods(false) - String.methods(false)
```

STDOUT:

```
235
235
3
19
[:json_create, :yaml_tag, :const_missing, :allocate, :new, :superclass, :cattr_reader, :cattr_writer, :cattr_accessor, :class_attribute, :superclass_delegating_accessor, :descendants, :subclasses, :duplicable?, :json_creatable?, :to_yaml]
```

From above output i just see that `methods` and `public_methods` are not same but can't find out what is exactly difference between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Object class documentation for [`Object#public_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-public_methods):

> Returns the list of **public methods** accessible to obj. If the all parameter is set to **false**, only those **methods in the receiver** will be listed.

In contrast, the documentation for [`Object#methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-methods) state:

> Returns a list of the names of **public and protected** methods of obj. This will include all the methods accessible in obj’s ancestors. If the optional parameter is **false**, it returns an array of obj‘s public and protected **singleton** methods, the array will not include methods in modules included in obj.

So:

1. `#public_methods` returns only the methods which are public, whereas `#methods` returns also (names of) protected methods.
2. The `false` parameter has different effects. I'm not too sure about the scope of the difference, but it seems to me that the main difference would be **singleton** methods vs. **instance methods***.

---

*'instance methods' can also refer to class methods if class is the receiver - as everything is an object and, as stated in the [Class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html):

> Classes in Ruby are first-class objects---each is an instance of class Class.

Comment: Do you mean `methods` return all public and protected  methods ? whereas `public_methods` return only public methods.

Comment: Yes. That is the basics of it.

Comment: When call both `methods` and `public_methods` without **false** it return same number methods for `String`. If `methods` return both public and protected methods then `methods(false).size` should return greater value then `public_methods(false).size`  is not it? but i see they return `3` and `19` respectively. So, am i missing something ? if they react differently with parameter `false` do you know what is that  exactly?

Comment: It's very likely that there are no protected methods unless you defined any... Try defining a protected method to experiment. Regarding the 'false', I'm not too sure what the documentation meant.

Comment: @Engr.HasanuzzamanSumon, after some more research I updated the answer with regards to the `true`/`false` optional parameter.